# New to C++ finding results of an if and else function

Tags: c++

```
result = getResult( 2, 5)
   
int getResult(int m, int n)
{
  int ans;

  if (m < n)
    if (n <= 10)     
      ans = m + n;
    else
      ans = m * n;
  else
    ans = n / m;

  return (ans);
}
```

I am stuck between 10 and 2,

does the second else apply because the second if is true? or do i still go with the first else?

Comment: Please format your code, it's difficult to reason this way.

Comment: What does "I am stuck between 10 and 2" mean?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Use braces, `{` and `}` after an `if` statement and after an `else` statement.  This should help you decode your code.

Answer (score 1):

For `m = 2, n = 5`, the first two `if` conditions are valid: `m < n` and `n <= 10`. Thus, `ans = m + n = 7` and it's not modified later on, so we expect `7` as the answer.

This can be much easier deduced if you properly format your code (I did it for you in this case). Also, if you use `{}` in `if`/`else`, that's way easier and less error-prone.